# Why cv2.NORM_HAMMING gives different value than actual hamming distance?

Tags: python, opencv, distance, hamming-distance

I am using the [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) to compute the difference among two keypoints descriptors obtained by the [BRISK descriptor from opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html). I follow the [suggestion of opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html) and use **cv2.NORM_HAMMING** while computing the distance as follows:

```
dist_opencv = cv2.norm(des_1,des_2,cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
```

It provides a value 87.0 among two descriptors. However, according to [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) description this is incorrect. I followed two alternative approaches (implement in python) to verify this:

```
dist_alt_app_1 = len(np.where(np.abs(des_1 - des_2)>0)[0])
dist_alt_app_2 = sum(el1 != el2 for el1, el2 in zip(des_1, des_2))
```

Both of dist_alt_app_1 and dist_alt_app_2 provides a value 43 which is not similar to 87.0 obtained from opencv. Did some search to know the reason for this difference. But did not find an explanation and clarification.

Can anyone please provide an explanation for this difference? Thanks in advance.

=============
**Adding an example here (to make the question more generalized):**

```
des_1 = [180  25 195  96  96  88   0   0]
des_2 = [244  27 195  96  96 192   0   0]
```

for the above two descriptors, dist_opencv = 5.0 and the others (dist_alt_app_1 and dist_alt_app_2) gives 3. While 3 is the correct Hamming distance why opencv provides 5.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your values:

```
180  25 195  96  96  88   0   0 
244  27 195  96  96 192   0   0
```

In binary

```
10110100 ‭00011001‬ ‭11000011‬ ‭01100000‬ ‭01100000‬ ‭01011000‬ 00000000 00000000
‭11110100‬ ‭00011011‬ ‭11000011‬ ‭01100000‬ ‭01100000‬ ‭‭11000000‬ 00000000 00000000
 ^             ^                             ^  ^^
```

I count 5 differences => Hamming distance is 5 => OpenCV is correct

---

Tip:

You can compute the Hamming distance between two values by counting the number of "1" after XOR-ing the two values. Pseudocode:

```
HammingDistance = count_1(xor(val1, val2))

01011000
‭‭11000000‬ 
-------- xor
10011000 => it has 3 "1"
```

Comment: +1, so its because of bitwise difference computed by opencv? Any suggestion of what should be an acceptable difference threshold among two descriptors?

Comment: Yes, hamming distance is compute bitwise. No, it doesn't have much sense to define a threshold on the distance between two descriptors. You'd better sort all your matches by distance, and keep only the first N, or the ones under the median value, or so on...